# How to change the color of a pie chart in react-chartjs-2 based on the theme in a Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project and using the react-chartjs-2 library to display a pie chart. Everything works fine in the default light mode theme, but I'm having trouble changing the chart color when the theme is switched to dark mode.

I have implemented the dark mode functionality in my project, and it's working correctly for other components. However, I can't figure out how to dynamically change the color of the pie chart based on the theme.

I've explored the react-chartjs-2 documentation, but couldn't find any specific instructions for handling theme-based color changes. I've also tried modifying the chart options directly, but that didn't yield the desired results either.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this? How can I dynamically update the color of the pie chart in react-chartjs-2 when the theme is changed to dark mode in my Next.js project?

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My code:

chartData.ts

```
    export interface ILegends{
  title: string
  value: string
  color: string
}

export const doughnutLegends: ILegends[] = [
  { title: 'Total Spent', value:'$ 12,342', color: '#FF708D' },
  { title: 'Overclocking Equivalent', value:'$ 12,342', color: '#884DFF' },
]

export const doughnutOptions = {
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [70, 30],
        /**
         * These colors come from Tailwind CSS palette
         * https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors/#default-color-palette
         */
        backgroundColor: ['#FF708D', '#884DFF'],
        // borderWidth: 1,
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        // borderColor: '#232E52',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 10,
        text: '23%',
        spacing: 2,
      },
    ],
    labels: ['Total Spent', 'Overclocking Equivalent'],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    cutout: '85%',
    plugins: {
      legend: {
         position: 'bottom',
      }
   }
  },
}
```

here how I use it in my code,

```
<div className="flex md:flex-1 flex-col mt-5 md:mt-0 md:ml-4 shadow-lg bg-white dark:bg-[#232E52] rounded-lg justify-center items-center">
          <p className="text-lg p-5 text-[#222B45] dark:text-white">
            Compute Savings
          </p>
          <p className="text-sm text-[#96A5B8] dark:text-white text-justify px-5">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing Lorem Ipsum is
            simply dummy text of the printingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            the printing
          </p>
          <div className="mt-12 flex items-center">
            <ChartCard title="">
              {<Doughnut {...doughnutOptions} />}
              {/* <ChartLegend legends={doughnutLegends} /> */}
            </ChartCard>
          </div>
        </div>
```